# Java - Thread Doesn't Stop

Tags: java, multithreading, key, awtrobot

I have the following class that's nested in another class (that also extends thread)

```
public class Miner extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }
    public boolean getRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    private void MainLoop() {
        if(!running) {
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            return;
        }
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100 + (int)(Math.random()*randInt));
        } catch(Exception e) {}

        MainLoop();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainLoop();
    }
}
```

Then in the class that Miner is nested in I have

```
private void MainLoop() throws AWTException {
    Miner miner = new Miner();
    miner.start();
    ... does other stuff ...
    while(miner.getRunning())
        miner.setRunning(false);
    ... do more stuff ...
    MainLoop();
}
```

However, after my attempt at setting running to false and stopping the miner thread and doing "do more stuff", that whole time I am doing "do more stuff" it is still pressing the D key.
Full MainLoop() method for class containing Miner.

```
private void MainLoop() throws AWTException {
        if(stop)
            return;
        Miner miner = new Miner();
        miner.start();
        while(true) {
            BufferedImage screenCap = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));
            int c = screenCap.getRGB(0,0);
            int  red = (c & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int  green = (c & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int  blue = c & 0x000000ff;
            Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);
            if(color.equals(DRILL_COLORS[0]) || color.equals(DRILL_COLORS[1]))
                break;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch(Exception e) {}
            if(stop)
                return;
        }
        while(miner.getRunning())
            miner.setRunning(false);
        count++;
        if(count >= 3) {
            up = !up;
            count = 0;
        }

        switch(moveDir) {
            case 0:
                if(up)
                    holdKey(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 100 + (int)(Math.random()*randInt));
                else
                    holdKey(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 100 + (int)(Math.random()*randInt));
                break;
            case 1:
                if(up)
                    holdKey(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 100 + (int)(Math.random()*randInt));
                else
                    holdKey(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 100 + (int)(Math.random()*randInt));
                break;
        }

        switch(wallLoc) {
            case 0:
                holdKey(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 50);
                break;
            case 1:
                holdKey(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 50);
                break;
            case 2:
                holdKey(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 50);
                break;
            case 3:
                holdKey(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 50);
                break;
        }

        MainLoop();
    }
```

The goal is basically to have the Miner thread press down the D key until it detects a certain color on a point on my screen. Then it should stop the miner thread while it moves my character a bit and then re-call the method and start all over again. But the miner thread runs the whole time.

Comment: In your code you have your condition to check to see if the robot is running or not, `if(!running) {...}`. Right below it you also have it to press the "D" key and then release it. The keyPress will still be carried out if the robot `running=true` or if `running=false`. Try commenting out the `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);` and see what happens.

Comment: Inside the `if(!running)` block I release the key to be sure its not being pressed, and then I call `return` so that it breaks from the method looping anymore.

Comment: You're correct, sorry didn't notice that.

Comment: Mind putting the rest of the code in there? The "do more stuff" bits. I can't find an issue with that segment. It could be caused else where that is setting `running` back to `true`.

Comment: I added the rest of the method

Answer (score 2):

There is no `stop` conidion here:

```
private void MainLoop() throws AWTException {
    Miner miner = new Miner();
    miner.start();
    ... does other stuff ...
    while(miner.getRunning())
        miner.setRunning(false);
    ... do more stuff ...
    MainLoop();
}
```

The method at the end calls itself => `MainLoop();`, this is a recursive infinite loop.
In this method a new `Miner` object is crated, a new thread is started, `D` is pressed again, then the thread is stopped, then `...do more stuff..` and then the whole cycle starts again.

Comment: In the `if(!running)` block though I put a `return` statement which I thought would stop the mining.

Comment: `if(runing` is in `Minesr` class - this condition stops the thread, but  not `private void MainLoop()` method.

Comment: I intend for the loop to essentially go on forever, but the problem is `miner` keeps on pressing D even while "do more stuff" should be occurring. My attempt at stopping the thread before that point is not working.

Comment: Insert some logging (debug) commands, or even simmple `System.out.println(...)` calls into Miner#MainLoop and into private#MainLoop methods, and you will see in the log how the code behaves.

Comment: I've tried, but the problem is that by the time do more stuff is called the miner thread hasnt stopped even though I stopped it right before then.

Comment: Note that the infinite recursion that has been pointed is a problem.  eventually you will likely run out of stack space (each call puts information on the stack if you keep calling yourself your stack will grow until it reaches max size in the thread.